# Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountExample$Map not found

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using ubuntu system and trying to run wordcount.jar program.    Unfortunately, I am having the following error -

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountExample$Map not found

I have updated the classpath as it is -

job.setJarByClass(WordCountExample.class);
and 
jobconf.setJarByClass(WordCountExample.class);

None of this work. Don't know what is wrong. Please share your expatriate in this regards.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
```

/**
 * @author http://www.devinline.com
 */

```
public class WordCountExample {
/* Map class which job will use and execute it map method */
public static class Map extends
Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
String line = value.toString();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
context.write(word, one);
}}}

/* Reduce class which job will use and execute it reduce method */
public static class Reduce extends
Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
int sum = 0;
for (IntWritable val : values) {
sum += val.get();
}
context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

/* Created a job with name wordCountExample */
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "wordCountExample");
job.setJarByClass(WordCountExample.class);  

/*
* Handler string and int in hadoop way: for string hadoop uses Text
* class and for int uses IntWritable */
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

/*
 * Configure map and reducer class, based on which it uses map and
    /* reduce method
     */
job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    /* Input and output format set as TextInputFormat */
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    /* addInputPath - passes input file path to job */
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    /* setOutputPath - passes output path to job */
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    /* Submit the job to the cluster and wait for it to finish. */
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 1 : 0);
}}
```

hadoop jar /home/nahmed/WordcountSample.jar WordCountExample /user/nahmed/pg20417.txt /user/nahmed/WCoutput
19/08/15 21:31:12 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at it066431.massey.ac.nz/130.123.248.83:8050

19/08/15 21:31:12 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at it066431.massey.ac.nz/130.123.248.83:10200
19/08/15 21:31:12 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
19/08/15 21:31:12 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
19/08/15 21:31:12 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
19/08/15 21:31:12 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
19/08/15 21:31:12 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1562128011754_0026
19/08/15 21:31:13 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
19/08/15 21:31:13 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1562128011754_0026
19/08/15 21:31:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://it066431.massey.ac.nz:8088/proxy/application_1562128011754_0026/
19/08/15 21:31:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1562128011754_0026
19/08/15 21:31:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1562128011754_0026 running in uber mode : false
19/08/15 21:31:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
19/08/15 21:31:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1562128011754_0026_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountExample$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountExample$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2226)
    ... 8 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

19/08/15 21:31:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1562128011754_0026_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountExample$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountExample$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2226)
    ... 8 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

19/08/15 21:31:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1562128011754_0026_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountExample$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCountExample$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2226)
    ... 8 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

19/08/15 21:31:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
19/08/15 21:31:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1562128011754_0026 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1562128011754_0026_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

19/08/15 21:31:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 13
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=4
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=4
        Other local map tasks=3
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=53207
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=7601
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=0
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=7601
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=54483968
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested classes: Map and Reduce. The error says that java was not able to find find them. Most probably the jar /home/nahmed/WordcountSample.jar doesn't contains them. Verify that executing:

```
 jar -tf  /home/nahmed/WordcountSample.jar
```

If they were not included in the jar, I think the issue the way you compile.

Comment: please correct me if I am doing anything wrong. the following command shows me the java class.   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WordCountExample$Map.class
WordCountExample$Reduce.class
WordCountExample.class
WordCountExample.java
.classpath
.project
input.txt
output/._SUCCESS.crc
output/.part-r-00000.crc
output/_SUCCESS
output/part-r-00000 I am using the following command to execute the command - hadoop jar WordcountSample.jar WordCountExample /user/nahmed/pg20417.txt /user/nahmed/WCoutput

Comment: The text is not very clear. It seems like you are adding to the jar/war the output of the WC execution. How do you compile?